# How can I upload a .csv file with python to Cassandra?

Tags: python, csv, cassandra, upload

I want to import a csv file in cassandra using python script. I don't know how

Comment: Just a heads up, but you probably received a couple of downvotes because of the lack of detail in the question.  For the future, you'll get better responses if you start trying to build something, and you can ask a specific question about a problem or error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a simple solution, you could always use `cqlsh`'s `COPY` utility.

```
> COPY myTable (col1, col2, col3, col4) FROM 'temp.csv' WITH HEADER=true;
```

I'd go with either `COPY` or [DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading) before building something new in Python.  In fact, `cqlsh` uses the Python driver and is already built to handle things like paging, batch sizes, timeouts, etc.

Documentation: [COPY FROM](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)

**Edit 20210903**

If you're set on querying w/ CQL and processing a result set in Python, you'll want to do something like this...

The import section will look something like this:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
```

First establish your connection:

```
auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=username, password=password)
cluster = Cluster(nodes,auth_provider=auth_provider)
session = cluster.connect()
```

Then build your query as a `SimpleStatement`.

```
strCQL = f"SELECT * FROM {keyspace}.{table}"
print(strCQL)

statement = SimpleStatement(strCQL,fetch_size=100)
rows = session.execute(statement)
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Note that you can also `print` individual column values with their ordinal index on `row` (`row[0]`,`row[1]`, etc).

In the above example, I'm setting the fetch size to 100.  It defaults to 5000, but if the [result set is large](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.25/query_paging/#paging-large-queries), you'll want that to be smaller to avoid timeouts.

[Link to my Git repo](https://github.com/aploetz/python_scripts/blob/master/exportTableByKey.py) for reference.

Comment: COPY is only for cqlsh... I need a CQL instruction to use in python...

Comment: @Mark031 Edit made.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DataStax Bulk Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html) tool (DSBulk) to bulk load data in CSV format to a Cassandra table.

Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [DSBulk Intro + Loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)
- Blog - [More DSBulk Loading examples](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Docs - [Loading data examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkLoad.html)
- Answered questions - [DS Community](https://community.datastax.com/topics/dsbulk.html)

DSBulk is open-source so it's free to use. Cheers!